# nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: cuda error: no cuda-capable device is detected

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I am using nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel image and tried to run it. But I get the following error.

```
sudaraka@RnDCompute:~$ docker run -it --runtime=nvidia nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:368: container init caused \"process_linux.go:351: running prestart hook 1 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: exec command: [/usr/bin/nvidia-container-cli --load-kmods configure --ldconfig=@/sbin/ldconfig.real --device=all --compute --utility --require=cuda>=8.0 --pid=12053 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a72cba41e94578ff91c71ab56b07d8e9153386e43383482ac649419ae0a77220/merged]\\\\nnvidia-container-cli: initialization error: cuda error: no cuda-capable device is detected\\\\n\\\"\"".
```

It says that no cuda-capable device is detected. 
I have cuda 8.0 installed.

```
sudaraka@RnDCompute:~$ nvcc --version nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation Built on Mon_Jan_23_12:24:11_CST_2017 Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.62
```

As well as the driver.

```
sudaraka@RnDCompute:~$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module 384.98 Thu Oct 26 15:16:01 PDT 2017 GCC version: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
```

My docker version is 17.09.0-ce. What can be the problem for the error I am getting as no cuda-capable device is detected?

Thank You

Comment: I have the same error did you figure it out

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the installation was not done successfully, could you show the result of nvidia-smi? , you should try to install cuda and nvidia-driver in a separate mode, like this:

cuda 9.2 and nvidia-driver 396

#### CUDA

- wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.2/Prod2/local_installers/cuda_9.2.148_396.37_linux
- sudo chmod 777 cuda_9.2.148_396.37_linux
- sudo sh cuda_9.2.148_396.37_linux

Several questions here, do not in the following:

- Install NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver (N)
- Do you want to install the OpenGL libraries? (N)
- Do you want to run nvidia-xconfig? (N)

#### NVIDIA

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install nvidia-396

After installation **cuda** it will be in /usr/local/cuda, and test nvidia driver with **nvidia-smi**

Install, **docker** and **nvidia-docker** too, and test test:

- docker run -it --runtime=nvidia nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel

  or
- nvidia-docker run -it --runtime=nvidia nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel

I hope it's useful, let me know!